# How to use \makebox in \tl_map_function?

Tags: boxes, expl3, arguments

While trying to answer [LaTeX for music](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267615/4918) I came to the problem that I can’t use a `\makebox` inside the function for a `\tl_map_function:NN` call. The problematic line is commented out in the following code.

With the line I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \color@endgroup used!
l.43 \function{T}{3---4, ..7-8}
```

When replacing the `#1` inside the `\makebox` argument by e.g. `x` there’s no error. Using `\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }` and `\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl` in the argument I get the same error.

***So how can I use the `\makebox` (or another box of fixed width) in this context?***

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\dim_new:N \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim
\dim_set:Nn \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim { 0.5em }

\tl_new:N \g_palamas_line_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_palamas_line_tl { \rule [ 0.7ex ] { \dim_use:N \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim } { 0.3pt } }
\tl_new:N \g_palamas_space_tl
\tl_set:Nn \g_palamas_space_tl { \hspace { \dim_use:N \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim }  }

\cs_new:Npn \palamas_makebox:n #1 {
% DOESN'T WORK:
%   \makebox [ \dim_use:N \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim ] [ r ] { #1 }
% DOESN'T WORK:
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
   \makebox [ \dim_use:N \l_palamas_boxwidth_dim ] [ r ] { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
% WORKS:
%   #1
}
\cs_new:Npn \palamas_process_list:n #1 {
   \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { \tl_use:N \g_palamas_line_tl }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { . } { \tl_use:N \g_palamas_space_tl }
   \tl_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_tl \palamas_makebox:n
   \\
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \function } { m O{0.1em} m } {
   #1
   \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #3 }
   \kern#2
   {
      \tiny
      \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
         \clist_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_clist \palamas_process_list:n
         \int_compare:nT { \clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist < 3 } { \\ }
      \end{tabular}
   }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\function{T}{3---4, ..7-8} \qquad
\function{D}{4---3, 6-5, ..7-8} \qquad
\function{D}{{11}---,4---3, 6-5--, ..7-8} \qquad
\function{s}{6,5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note you are not following the indenting and spacing guidelines of expl3 :)

Comment: @Manuel: Yep … I know, but I prefer my style ;-)

Comment: Well, the guidelines are there for a reason, I think having some sort of consensus is good. If this code will never be public, okey, but if something is to be published, it's nice if it follows the guidelines. I personally (after some time) can read much faster expl3 code (if it's correctly formatted).

Comment: Well … I used the official formatting for some packages but I can read my style better and since I’m am the one who works most with the code, I like it to do ist _my way_ ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing a mapping of a token list and

```
\tl_use:N \g_palamas_line_tl
```

are *two* distinct items in the token list and `\palamas_makebox:n { \tl_use:N }` is what eventually produces the error.

Either brace the item

```
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { - } { {\tl_use:N \g_palamas_line_tl} }
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { . } { {\tl_use:N \g_palamas_space_tl} }
```

or just remove `\tl_use:N`. By the way, you should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` in both cases where you have `\cs_new:Npn`; and `\dim_use:N` is wrong in each place you have it.

Comment: Great, that solved the problem. Thanks! One questions: So all `\xx_use:N` are only to be used when I want to “print” the content in the output i.e. where I’d use `\the` in LaTeX2e?

Comment: @Tobi Not really; but in all your use cases of `\dim_use:N`, the rules allow a register, so `\dim_use:N` just makes TeX do more work.